# Exporting terabytes from an AWS Snowball Edge to an on prem resource

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-snowball

Complete AWS noob here -

We are in the position of needing to export around a couple terabytes of data from an AWS snowball that was dropped into our hands into an on prem storage solution. The problem is that nobody on our small team is familiar with AWS or scripting.

Does anyone have recommendations of what direction to go or scripts that will copy all of the data?

Thank you in advance.

We've tried the `aws s3 cp <source> <destination> --recursive` cmd, but unfortunately it is only copying 1000 objects. We've also tried to utilize the `aws s3 sync` cmd as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. The problem is due to AWS Snowball devices not being fulling compatible with the most recent AWS CLI software. According to  Amazon "[Snowball Edge devices support only version 1.16.14 and earlier of the AWS CLI for use with the Amazon S3 adapter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/snowball/latest/developer-guide/using-adapter.html)". Using the 1.16.14 AWS CLI avoids the 1000 object limit.